# Favorite tags have been moved down; can we have them back to the top?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, tag-watching, usability

I now have to scroll down one whole page in order to open the tag-specific pages. I find this disturbing.

[image: follow the arrow]

This is how it was and should be.

[image: now!]

Comment: Never noticed. I've written a User style to disable the adverts at the right.

Comment: @RobW: out of principle (some sites deserve ads incomes), I don't block the ads.

Comment: That bird better not poop on any of my pages!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After discussing this a bit internally we've reverted this change *for now* and done a build to push.  The change isn't *just* moving these things, there's another component to it you'll see soon, hopefully next week.

There may yet be a shuffle of the sidebar associated with that, we'll see when that comes...but we will keep the favorite tags as nav use case in mind (I often use them this was as well) when deciding what to do.  Not tagging this [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) because I can't promise it'll be a permenant change.

Comment: You do intend to keep the control in a consistant place though, right? The other sidebar elements shift around but actual controls like that shouldn't move of course.

Comment: @Ben - I can't say for certain...this isn't my feature, just addressing the meta concern here since I was at a computer for a little bit. I'll actually be in Philly next week with part of the team at the emerging tech conference when this is deployed.

Comment: Hmm, I'm intrigued about what this mystery feature is...Also, since you guys will be in my neck of the woods, `<obligatory offering of food and/or drinks />`. The venue's actually in an exceptionally good location for that kind of thing.

Answer (score 6):

### Option 1: Move the tag container to the top

#### Chrome extension

How to use: Drag this userscript to Chrome, Firefox (possibly Opera and IE). Chrome will automatically convert it to a Content Script.

Currently, only https://stackoverflow.com/ is added.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Tags 2 top
// @description    Place the tags at Stack Overflow at the top
// @namespace      Rob W
// @match          https://stackoverflow.com/*
// ==/UserScript==
var tags = document.getElementById('interesting-tags'),
    sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
if (tags && sidebar) sidebar.insertBefore(tags, sidebar.firstChild);
```

#### Not Enough jQuery

The previous code was written in pure DOM, because that's the most straightforward way in a Chrome extension. For GreaseMonkey scripts, jQuery can also be used:

```
unsafeWindow.$('#interesting-tags').prependTo('#sidebar');
```

### Option 2: Hide the ads

In Firefox, I'm using the following UserStyle ([Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/stylish/) (also available in Chrome, btw)):

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
@-moz-document domain('stackoverflow.com'),
               domain('stackexchange.com'),
               domain('superuser.com'),
               domain('serverfault.com'),
               domain('stackapps.com'),
               domain('askubuntu.com') {
  #adzerk1, #adzerk2, /* right panel advert, spotted at TeX */
  .ad-container, /* right panel advert */
  #hireme, /* <-- right panel advert, VV--- Tag advert */
  div[style="height:135px;width:100%;padding-bottom:5px;"] {
      display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: -1 not enough jQuery. +2 did not give me seizure :P

Comment: @Manishearth Added jQuery to the Greasemonkey method :p

Comment: Can't +1 again, unfortunately (I made a mistake in my first comment, meant -1+2)

Comment: Actually GM is the most straightforward way in Chrome--GM built in

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I split GM script into new subsection and explained how to install.

Comment: @Manishearth Chrome != Greasemonkey. Extensions in Chrome run in an isolated environment, which means that global properties are not available.

Comment: I rollbacked. You could always use with_jquery to make the script run on Chrome/

Comment: OK, you fixed it..

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bookmarklet for you that makes them come to the top and try to catch your eye:

```
 javascript:function A(){for(i=0;i-DIL;i++){DIS=DI[i].style;DIS.position="absolute";DIS.left=Math.sin(R*x1+i*x2+x3)*x4+x5+"px";DIS.top=Math.cos(R*y1+i*y2+y3)*y4+y5+"px"}R++}R=0;x1=.1;y1=.05;x2=.25;y2=.24;x3=1.6;y3=.24;x4=300;y4=200;x5=300;y5=200;DI=$("#interestingTags a");DIL=DI.length;setInterval("A()",20);void 0
```

I'm no fan of favorite tags myself, but I feel that the tags should be back where they were. SO's ads are only effective since *we* add good content. We don't really need to be shown the ads--we've seen them millions of times. I know that's not going to happen, but hampering our productivity(hiding the favtags) with an ad--one that's pointless to show us-- seems nonsensical.

Update: If you like this so much that you want it done to ALL tags,

```
 javascript:function A(){for(i=0;i-DIL;i++){DIS=DI[i].style;DIS.position="absolute";DIS.left=Math.sin(R*x1+i*x2+x3)*x4+x5+"px";DIS.top=Math.cos(R*y1+i*y2+y3)*y4+y5+"px"}R++}R=0;x1=.1;y1=.05;x2=.25;y2=.24;x3=1.6;y3=.24;x4=300;y4=200;x5=300;y5=200;DI=$(".post-tag");DIL=DI.length;setInterval("A()",20);void 0
```

Comment: I'd like to report a bug - one of them actually poked me in the eye.  For what its worth it was the **Facebook** tag and my **right eye**.

Comment: @Lix: [status-bydesign]

Comment: In that case -1

Comment: Haha, this speeds up each time you click the bookmarklet =)